# Cannot make HTTPS work between CloudFront and Elastic BeanStalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to setup HTTPS across my app which consists in a frontend (S3 bucket distributed with CloudFront), and a backend (node.js app inside Elastic Beanstalk).

For the CloudFront part, I created an SSL certificate in N. Virginia (apparently I don't have a choice here) and I made the binding in the CloudFront distribution. It works and my app is served over HTTPS.

For the Elastic Beanstalk part, I created an SSL certificate in Ireland (where my EBS app is hosted) and I bound this certificate to the EBS load balancer using the port 443. It works and I can reach my server with HTTPS using Postman.

However, when my frontend tries to make an API call to the backend I get this error :[image]

I guess I made a mistake while creating the certificates, but I cannot find it. I gave both certificates the same set of CNAMES, I am not sure if I am supposed to do that.

**EDIT :**

I get the exact same error after updating the frontend so that it points the DName of the load balancer (also mapped to subdomain with Route 53).

[image]

Comment: Based on your screenshot it looks like you're making your request directly against your EB environment URL (`eu-west-1`). You want to make the request to the load balancer which will in turn deliver it to the EB application. You will find this in the Description section after selecting your load balancer in EC2 -> Load Balancers (`DNS name`). Though ideally you would use Route53 to map a domain/sub-domain to this resource, and then make your call against that.

Comment: @dusthaines I just did what you said and I still get the exact same error. I created an alias in Route 53 mapping "debug.api.djumbo.net" to the DName of the load balancer. Should I also update the certificate itself ?

Comment: @dusthaines that won't help anything here, those are both DNS records pointing at the same load balancer. The issue is that the SSL certificate installed on the load balancer does not (and can not) match either of those domain names. To use an SSL certificate on the load balancer here it is required to use a custom domain that matches the SSL certificate, otherwise you get the SSL certificate validation error in the above screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CloudFront is attempting to load an HTTPS URL from your load balancer. I assume you have an SSL certification assigned to the load balancer. The domain name of the SSL certificate on the load balancer needs to match the domain name that CloudFront is requesting.

For example if the load balancer's SSL certificate is something like `beanstalk.mydomain.com` then CloudFront would need to be making requests for `https://beanstalk.mydomain.com`. The error CloudFront is giving you says that the domain name of the SSL certificate served by the load balancer does not match the domain name `djumbo-back-debug.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.co`.

You need to setup something like the following:

- DNS Name `www.mydomain.com` points to CloudFront Distribution

  - Configured to serve `www.mydomain.com`
  - Configured with an SSL certificate for the domain `www.mydomain.com`
  - Configure to pull from the origin `beanstalk.mydomain.com`
- DNS Name `beanstalk.mydomain.com` points to Elastic Beanstalk application

  - With a Load Balancer, with an SSL certificate for `beanstalk.mydomain.com`

Comment: Thank you so much. My mistake was that I did not enter the proper CNames for the EBS SSL certificate. I entered `djumbo.net` and `*.djumbo.net` hoping it would cover `debug.api.djumbo.net`, but it didn't. I created a new certificate with the CNames `api.djumbo.net` and `debug.api.djumbo.net`, now it works :)

Comment: @Louis - one last order of housekeeping - consider adding a listener to your load balancer for `HTTP : 80`, having a rule of: `Redirect to... HTTPS 443`. Not the end of the world, but should anyone enter your domain without the protocol this will ensure all traffic flows through SSL. A quick test of the debug domain you noted looks like you don't have that in place (`https` get a 200 while `http` fails). Good luck!

Comment: @dusthaines why open extra ports on the load balancer if requests should be coming through CloudFront? I would setup the HTTP->HTTPS redirect on CloudFront and leave only the minimal configuration on the load balancer to allow CloudFront to connect to it.

Comment: @MarkB - as I understood the architecture based on Louis original question there are two primary asset: Frontend ⟶ [S3 via CloudFront] and Backend ⟶ [EB via EC2 LB]. Each having its own sub-domain. So the protocol config for CloudFront would not impact the LB and vice versa. My suggestion is probably excessive since presumably the frontend would be the singular client making requests to the backend. But none the less, the backend does have a unique DNS endpoint and if it were to be exposed or shared with others I think it's a best practice to plan for all traffic to flow through HTTPS.

Comment: @dusthaines I read it as CloudFront connecting to Elastic Beanstalk over HTTPS. If that's not the case then the question title makes no sense. After reading the question again though, I think you are correct, and the question is confusing the issue by including some entirely irrelevant CloudFront information.

Comment: Indeed, there are some irrelevant CloudFront informations in my post. However, this was not obvious to me by the time I opened the question, especially because the error showed up exclusively when requesting the backend from my CloudFront distribution while everything was fine using an http client.

Comment: @Louis the backend to your CloudFront distribution is S3, not Elastic Beanstalk. Unless you have also configured CloudFront to use your Elastic Beanstalk as an origin, which you haven't indicated in your question.